# How to access to checked items from another form?

Tags: c#

I have two forms: form1 and form2.

form1 contains `button1` and `listbox1`, form2 contains `button2` and `checkedlistbox1`.

When click to the `button1` must open `form2`  and check items for `checkedlistbox1`. Then click `button2` so `form2` closed and `listbox1` must show checked items from `checkedlistbox1`. But the problem that I can't copy checked items from `checkedlistbox1` to `listbox1`. How can i do that, please help.

Answer (score 3):

So we'll start by adding this property to `Form2`.  It will be the meat of the communication:

```
public IEnumerable<string> CheckedItems
{
    get
    {
        //If the items aren't strings `Cast` them to the appropirate type and 
        //optionally use `Select` to convert them to what you want to expose publicly.
        return checkedListBox1.SelectedItems
            .OfType<string>();
    }
    set
    {
        var itemsToSelect = new HashSet<string>(value);

        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            checkedListBox1.SetSelected(i,
                itemsToSelect.Contains(checkedListBox1.Items[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

This will let us set the selected items (feel free to use something other than `string` for the item values) from another form, or get the selected items from this form.

Then in `Form1` we can do:

```
private  void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 other = new Form2();
    other.CheckedItems = listBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<string>();
    other.FormClosed += (_, args) => setSelectedListboxItems(other.CheckedItems);
    other.Show();
}

private void setSelectedListboxItems(IEnumerable<string> enumerable)
{
    var itemsToSelect = new HashSet<string>(enumerable);
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        listBox1.SetSelected(i , itemsToSelect.Contains(listBox1.Items[i]));
    }
}
```

When we click the button we create an instance of the second form, set it's selected indexes, add a handler to the `FormClosed` event to update our listbox with the new selections, and then show the form.  You'll note the implementation of th emethod to set teh `ListBox` items is of exactly the same pattern as in `CheckedItems`'s `set` method.  If you find yourself doing this a lot consider refactorizing it out into a more general method.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Please don't edit code in other user's answers just to follow coding conventions you're used to.  If there was a problem with it then that's different, but making an edit just to use a naming convention you prefer isn't the intended purpose of suggested edits.

Comment: I thought you have a typo, because `_` is a name I have never seen before

Comment: @lazyberezovsky An underscore `_` is a perfectly valid identifier for a variable in C#.  By convention it's used to represent an unused parameter for a lambda.  It's just there to ensure it matches the signature of the delegate.  If I were to actually use it (I never would, since I already have a strongly typed variable representing the other form) I would give it a different name.

Comment: `args` is also unused parameter

Comment: Holy nice code, Batman!  Very cool use of "OfType" and lambdas.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Yep, but I already was using `_` for another one, and using `__` would just be cruel and unusual punishment ;) .  I also *sometimes* use `args` but I will *never* use sender when writing a lambda (the original sender object is *always* still in scope) so typing `(_, args)` is just a reflex for me.

Comment: @Servy OK ;) +1 and I really thought it was typo! (nothing about my coding conventions)